# Building for Bugs

Tags: sdk, release-management

How do you handle a bug in a specific SDK version in a released application? Say for example I've reported and received notification that a bug is known in a specific version of an SDK. Say the SDK engineers fix the problem in the next release. Do I then need to check if the user is running the buggy release and display an error message that they can't use a specific feature with a bug in it because it will crash their hardware? Is there a more graceful way? Do you display an alert and tell them to upgrade to the latest SDK? Do you completely remove the feature? Advice would be appreciated.

This is phrased to be agnostic as possible, but I am asking for the purposes of iPhone application development at this time. General answers for other platforms would be nice as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the nature of the bug and on the nature of the platform. With the iPhone, for example, you cannot just tell the user to upgrade his or her phone. If your goal is to support iPhone version X.Y, then you will need to support the corresponding SDK; whereas, targeting browser X version Y.Z or Java version X.Y, it may sometimes be acceptable to tell users to upgrade.*  Giving the impression that your application can do something only to give an error message saying that it cannot support it for that version of the platform does not make for a good user experience. If possible, try to work around the deficiency in the platform (by possibly reimplementing code that supposedly works in the SDK) and provide the feature to the user. If that isn't possible, then disable it when running on the deficient version of the platform, but be sure to remove all traces of that feature from the application (so that users don't click on a button only for it to tell them that the button is completely useless). I should add that conditionally enabling/disabling features is only sensible in the case where the feature is not essential to application; if a feature is a core aspect of the application, then you'd better find a workaround or raise the minimum requirements as it would not be appropriate to ship a deficient application to your users.

*An example where telling users to upgrade is not reasonable would be business applications, since business sys admins tend to be unusually lazy and users have no power to upgrade by themselves.

Comment: So this specific bug cripples my application. It's confirmed and others will also have the same issue. So my requirements are now two-fold: a minimum of 3.0 OS for 3.x devices, but then if you upgrade to 4.0 it breaks. I guess I'd have to say "Devices supported 3.0–3.1.3 but on 4.x 4.1 is required" in my marketing notes.